# no matches in array in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 5.2.2.

in my index I have data looking like this:

```
{
    "_index": "index",
    "_type": "273caf76-ec03-478c-b980-9743180bc863",
    "_id": "eee46e24-f383-4ae7-8930-dc3836e030a5",
    "_score": 3.41408,
    "_source": {
      "Father Name": [
        {
          "id": "some id",
          "value": "Some value test test"
        }
      ],
      "Mother Name": [
        {
          "id": "some id",
          "value": "Another value haha"
        }
      ],
      "Other values": [{ id: "", value: ""}]
    }
}
```

When I am searching with _all, everything works fine and I can find all the results with reasonable scores

```
{"query":{"match":{"_all":"value"}},"from":0,"size":20}
```

But that query is searching in all the fields. If I want for instance just to find results in `Father Name` or in `Father Name` and `Mother Name`, then I find nothing.

```
{"query":{"match":{"Father Name":"value"}},"from":0,"size":20}
```

My goal is to find in have a search like with _all, but limited to a few fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fields `Father Name` and `Mother Name` are **arrays of inner objects**.

To search within the `value` field within `Father Name`, for example, do

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty -d '
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Father Name.value": "first"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}'
```

I'm not sure, however, how to query for all fields within `Father Name`.

Reference [Arrays of Inner Objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/complex-core-fields.html#object-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Sam Shen's answer is the way to go if you need to configure which properties to use on a per-query basis.

One alternative is to configure the fields to not be included in the `_all` query.

For example, this would cause only `Father Name` to be included in the `_all` query, by disabling all the fields at the type level, then enabling all of the subfields on `Father Name`.

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "include_in_all": false,
      "properties": {
         "Father Name" : {
           "include_in_all": true
         }
      }
    }
}
```

You can set the [include_in_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/include-in-all.html) property on any level in the mapping, including subfield properties.

The big drawback here is that this isn't configured on a query-by-query basis, this is configured for all queries attempting to use the `_all` field.